# MySQL multiple records of same id

Tags: mysql

I have the following records

```
id    userid    number    revokeid
1     1         123       0
2     2         456       0
3     3         789       0
```

Overtime, more records will be added and modified

```
id    userid    number    revokeid
1     1         123       1
2     2         456       0
3     3         789       1
```

If this happens, I want to extract records that have revokeid = 1. Pretty simple.

```
id    userid    number    revokeid
1     1         123       1
2     2         456       0
3     3         789       1
4     1         147       0
```

As you can see, userid 1 was re-added. I would like extract records with the revokeid = 1. However, in the case of userid 1, where there is a revokeid = 0, it should not be extracted.

More records

```
id    userid    number    revokeid
1     1         123       1
2     2         456       0
3     3         789       1
4     1         147       0
5     4         258       0
6     5         369       1
7     5         321       0
8     6         123       0
```

I've been cracking my head for more than a week now. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Thanking you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE revokeid=1 AND userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM testtable WHERE revokeid=0);
```

`SELECT userid FROM testtable WHERE revokeid=0` gets all userids which have a non revoked account. These userids then get excluded in the first query.

The result then contains all entries which have revoked=1 excluding those where the userid have an id that is revoked=0.

Comment: Thanks @jony_93. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

"Extract" can mean one of two things here:

1: You want to SELECT those records:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE revokeid = 1
```

2: You want to DELETE those records:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE revokeid = 1
```

In both cases, you're just adding a WHERE clause and specifying the condition that the `revokeid` field should equal `1`. [For reference - see here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php).

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE revokeid=1` get you only the rows where revokeid is 1.

`DELETE FROM tablename WHERE revokeid=1` will delete the rows where revokeid is 1.

If you want to get a specific userid but only where revokeid is 0, you could use `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE userid=1 AND revokeid=0`

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean from your question.

Comment: `table` is a reserved word :)

Comment: Presumably he wouldn't copy it verbatim. I would expect him to change it to the name of his table but I suppose you're right.